# Why is there no consistent Chief Helms Officer in TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

After watching TNG and VOY, there is a rather major discrepancy: in TNG, there seems to be no consistent helms officer on the Enterprise-D, apart from when Wesley is in charge.  It seems to be some random Ensign that last about a week/month before a new one is put in charge.  Yet, in VOY, it's always Tom Paris (as is the case in TOS and ENT).  Why is this the case (possibly to give Ensigns experience or something)?

Comment: Question title seems to be backwards given the last sentence. (Also, Hikaru Sulu (TOS) and Travis Mayweather (ENT) would seem to indicate TNG was the inconsistent one)

Comment: Wasn't me.  Not sure if you intended me, but SE notified me.

Comment: @Izkata - I know you wouldn't DV it, but obviously someone with limited experience on SFSE

Comment: On Voyager; Lt. Ayala filled in on helm in Tom Paris' stead on occasion, don't forget

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Because the producer's gave Robert Duncan McNeill the role of Tom
  Paris, helm officer of the U.S.S Voyager and viewers don't want to see
  story-lines about random pilot of the week, nor did anyone want to pay someone
  else for a speaking role when you're giving McNeill the paycheck.
- It's often stated that Tom Paris is the best pilot they have onboard
  so that's probably why he ends up as permanent helm officer after the
  last one gets herself killed in the Pilot. But as we see, there's
  different shifts over the course of a day on Voyager and Paris must
  have counterparts driving the ship when he's taking a nap. We just
  don't see a lot of these other shifts because no one wants to see
  episodes which consist of the main cast sleeping.
- There's also a big discrepancy between job availability/advancement between U.S.S
  Voyager and U.S.S Enterprise. A lot of people are stuck doing the same jobs on Voyager that might have changed to different jobs on Enterprise, but probably not.
- Don't forget that on TNG we had regular helm officers too. In Season 1 we had Geordi flying the ship, while in Season 5 and 6 they had Ensign Ro. Wesley filled the role in Seasons 2-4. Also if you check out this link for [Flight Controllers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flight_controller) you can see that other helm officers had reoccurring appearances, so all were probably having off-screen adventures onboard the Enterprise between their appearances.